# Map still NULL after executing pending transactions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, google-play-services

So I have a Fragment Activity, and in it I have a WorldFragment. The WorldFragment has a  MapFragment, and a bunch of buttons overlayed on top of it. The MapFragment is thus a nested fragment. The MapFragment is being added dynamically to a FrameLayout in the WorldFragment. Here's the code:

```
 super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_world, container, false);

    if (mapFragment == null){
        mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
    }
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.world_map_container, mapFragment)
        .commit();
    getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();


    map = mapFragment.getMap();
      //  map.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));
```

So I know that comits are asynchronous, and based on the documentation calling executePendingTransactions() SHOULD wait for the transaction to be completed. But it doesn't work, the map is still null. It only works if I wrap this code in a handler:
    handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable(){

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            map = mapFragment.getMap();
              //  map.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));
        }

    });
```

I get that this should put the code in queue, but I don't actually seem to have any guarantee that the handler will definitely perform it's code after the map is done, so I feel like it could still be null in some cases. I would like to do this with either a callback, or by waiting for the transaction to be completed.

Is there a way to do this, without extending the SupportMapFragment class, and adding a listener and callback? Do fragment transactions have a callback somewhere? Or is there a reason why executePendingTransactions() is not working?

Edit: I have checked to see if executePendingTransactions is returning true, and it is saying there are transactions pending. I don't understand why it's not executing them though.

Comment: Did you ever settle on a solution?

Comment: @Kylel Sadly no, I haven't worked on that part of my app in a while but I never figured out why there were pending transactions that just weren't being executed.